# Where click once application installed

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I am afraid after publishing the click once application, from the users to access the installation folder and to view the app.config file

many concerns I have now

1. Is this possible on the client machine?
2. If yes where is the location of the installation?
3. Any idea how to secure the application for example from accessing app.config?

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, according to security rule #3: "If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore." - it's his computer, not yours.
2. Silverlight applications e.g. go into `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\` plus a more or less random name including the URL. Quite unlikely to be found by ordinary users, but not secure from hackers.
3. You can't. The file is read by the .NET framework itself. Otherwise, see 1)

Comment: the users are on an intranet, and the app.config storing critical details that it should not be exposed to any user

Comment: @HadeelSima: it depends a bit on what your application does and what exactly you want to protect. I'd not store sensitive data in app.config but in encrypted files. I need more details to answer this.